# Allowing users to upload csv data into parse app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, parse-platform

I need to let my users upload CSV data into my app. Data such as contacts, or products. Their are a number of web based client libraries that can handle the client side logic. What I am looking for is a fast reliable solution to get the data into a parse class.

I have not written any code. Right now I am trying to discover the best process to do this. I have played with parse batch save and know that is not reliable for 1000's of inserts. My thought is to upload the CSV store it in a parse class "uploads" and then have background job lift out say 100, or 1000 records at a time and insert them. Then send a notification when it is done.

Is this the best option, or has anybody found a simpler faster solution?